# Send ajax request on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mouseevent

I have a set of element with the same class selector. When I enter mouse on this element I want to send Ajax query, but. When I just `console.log(1);` on mouse enter all fine, but when I send request it rise in some progression, and each next hover send many requests instead of one.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('.device_hover').each(function (key, val) {
        $(val).mouseenter(function () {
            var val = $(this).html();
            console.log(1);

            $.ajax({
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': 'handlers/route_request.php',
                'dataType': 'html',
                'success': function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Can somebody help me? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You should provide a queue of requests in such a case. Keep in mind that each time you will be **entering on a .device_hover element (also, you don't need the .each.. $('.device_hover') will automatically bind an event listener to each DOM element with that class)** it will perform a request, which will result in a selvage polling. I would personally recommend you to use a flag or something like that to check whether the user is hovering an element or not (also, use .hover or .on('mouseover') instead of mouseenter), set a flag and execute the ajax request ONLY ONCE.

Comment: Add a status to the element that has already been hovered on, such data-ajax="done" and then on the next hover, if ajax==done do nothing.

Comment: @briosheje, thanks, but I want to be able repeat send ajax, when will hover second time. I need to somehov delete identifier. and what reasong to not use mouseenter?

Comment: @briosheje, solve this by add .on('mouseleave'

Comment: @excluded_once: you can set that flag to FALSE when the user leaves the element or use LShetty's idea basically you use .mouseleave to set the flag to false and .mouseenter to set the flag to true. In a nutshell, the idea is to execute an ajax request and, once it has been already executed, set the flag back to false. In this way you won't have an insanely long ajax queue if a user goes over and out many times in a short amount of time. In any case, .mouseenter triggers only if the hover happens from a parent div to a child one, while the .mouseover happens in both ways.

Comment: @briosheje, thanks it more clearly for me now. can you place it as answer I will accept it...

Comment: @excluded_once: I don't have a "practical" solution because when you deal with ajax requests you have to think a bit more before finding a proper solution. In my case, posting an answer being sure that it is correct is impossible, therefore I'm rather happier if I have helped you finding a solution to solve your problem, I would personally recommend you to try it and come back in this post if something doesn't work :P

Comment: @briosheje, thanks anyway, I am pretty new in JS world...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way is to use `hover` event for sending ajax request. This will send only once.

```
$(".device_hover").hover(function(){

   var val = $(this).html();
        console.log(1);

        $.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': 'handlers/route_request.php',
            'dataType': 'html',
            'success': function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
  }, function(){
    //This function is for unhover.
 });
```

Comment: I sure your solution is `hover`. Probably you are using `hover` in the wrong way .Every function you put inside hover event, will run **only once**. Please refer to [This link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_hover)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hover event, you can make use of onmouseenter and onmouseleave events to make a call only once.